# How do you wish someone a happy birthday using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking to wish my girlfriend a happy birthday and thought it would be cute to do it in a programming language. She's a programmer and uses objective-c. Help? :D

Comment: Too bad we don't have a tag called 'cheesy' :-)

Answer (score 1):

terrible question but you're a good b/f
so, assuming her birthday is tomorrow (6/28):

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];

if (day == 28 && month == 6){ 
    NSLog(@"Happy birthday!");
}
```

Comment: hopefully it's not a terrible idea to put all of this code on the cake ha ha. thanks for your help man! :)

Comment: Have fun :-) Hope she appreciates the effort